# How to make icon to be displayed in the fixed place in my site?

Tags: jquery, css

I have fixed an icon in the place using jQuery

```
$('#edit').css({left:  512});
```

**When i make the browser size small or big the icon is not on the same place. It's moving according to that current browser size.**

How can it be controlled using jQuery to place icon in the same place even the browser size changes.

Comment: You want fixed to what? The window? Try *position:fixed*. Only works if you have a window. Doesn't work on most mobile devices.

Comment: Can you show the HTML and CSS associated with this element as it's hard to put it in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using CSS instead of jQuery? Simply use **fixed positioning**.

Answer (score 1):

In the css class put :

.logoClass
{
  position : fixed;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'position :fixed;'